# Media won't show or allow to upload on Wordpress Media Library

Tags: wordpress

[image]

The media library only displays one thumb which is unidentified and stops downloading all previous media that were uploaded.

I do not know what seems to be the problem. I have disabled all plugins and tried but the problem still existed.

Anyone has this problem before? and how to solve it. Thank you.

Edited : Guys, thank you for your help. I have looked up online and it seemed like when I imported database, I didn't do it correctly which caused _postmeta and _posts to not have AUTO INCREMENT in the database. I am going to fix it and see if that helps.

> Just found the solution. When I migrated website from localhost, at
>   Settings>Media, somehow the localhost URL was remained there at Path
>   value. Therefore, I had to make a change there to be
>   wp-content/uploads

Comment: There's most likely a JavaScript error message. Check your web inspector for any potential XHR errors. The circle animation next to the "Bulk Select" button indicates there's still an Ajax request happening (or it has failed).

Answer (score 0):

In general to fix this problem you have to check the [file permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) of your `uploads` folder (`wp-content/uploads`). Try to set the numeric value to `755`.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the error as you are able to see it most probably this issue is occurring due to uploads folder permission issue.

Looking forward to help you more on this.

Comment: Hi there, the problem is not only about the media. Looks like posts and pages are affected too. I messed up the database import so I have to do it all over again. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Just reinstall the wordpress, may be installing issue